# Navigation Drawer + Viewpager + setVisibility = InflateException/NullPointer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I develops an Android Application and I'm facing some problems.

In my `MainActivity` I have the following components:

- Navigation Drawer (instanciates and loads many fragments)
- ViewPager (only for `ArticleFragment` which display the detail view of an article)

Normaly, the ViewPager is related to a specific Activity, but I really want to use both Navigation Drawer and ViewPager. The only way is to implement both elements in same activity.

The `DrawerLayout` is composed by the navigation drawer itself and by the content area. In my content area I have a `FrameLayout` and the `ViewPager`. The problem is that the `ViewPager` is always displayed.

So my idea was to play with the `android:visibility` property to show/hide alternately the FrameLayout and the ViewPager. If you look at my `activity_main.xml` you can notice the  `android:visibility` set to `invisible` on the `ViewPager`.

**/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- ViewPager -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="NavigationDrawerFragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the navigation drawer
        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        // Set up the viewpager
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    //-------------------------------//
    //       NAVIGATION DRAWER       //
    //-------------------------------//

    /**
     * Update the main content by replacing fragments
     */
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Boolean viewPagerArticles = false;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FooFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                viewPagerArticles = true;

                // Hide navigation drawer container and show the viewpager
                mContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.GONE);
                mPager.setVisibility(ViewPager.VISIBLE);

                // NullPointerException with new this line. Why?
                // Fragment already instanciate in ScreenSlidePagerAdapter -> getItem() -> ArticleFragment.create()?
                //fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Show the view pager and hide navigation drawer container
        // =================
        // THE BUG IS HERE
        // =================
        if (!viewPagerArticles) {
            mContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.VISIBLE);
            mPager.setVisibility(ViewPager.GONE);
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    ...

    //-------------------------------//
    //           VIEWPAGER           //
    //-------------------------------//

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return DayFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { ... }
    }
    ...
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

http://pastebin.com/LwKZnNiB

**Display ViewPager content**

On my `HomeFragment` I have a button with a onClickListener:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(2);
    }
});
```

When I load MainActivity I have these errors : InflateException and NullPointerException

```
AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.example.android.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.android.ui.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:117)
            at com.example.android.ui.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:202)
            at com.example.android.ui.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:80)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.example.android.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Everything is fine (no errors, activity loaded) without:

```
    // =================
    // THE BUG IS HERE
    // =================
    if (!viewPagerArticles) {
        mContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.VISIBLE);
        mPager.setVisibility(ViewPager.GONE);
    }
```

...but it does not match my expectations because the Navigation Drawer fragments are always hiding (it's normal because of `mContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.GONE);`. I just want to inverse the mContainer/mPager visibilities.

I hope I was enough clear...!

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that `NullPointerException` because the of the way you built the `NavigationDrawerFragment` fragment. More precisely, in its `onCreate()` method you call `selectItem()` which propagates through the `Activity`(registered as a listener) to the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` callback. The problem is that the fragment will be inflated at the point when `setContentView()` is called(in `onCreate()`) which means you'll enter the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` callback before the lines:

```
mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

run, rendering those references `null` in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()`.

To solve this you could simply replace the current `<fragment />` tag from the `Activity` layout with a basic container(a placeholder empty `FrameLayout` for example) and add the `NavigationDrawerFragment` manually in `onCreate()` after the lines above(where you bind the views). There could be another better solution(or I could make other suggestions) but it's not very clear how you want to handle the visibility. Maybe you can expand on this.

**Edit 2**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the navigation drawer
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);


    // Set up the viewpager
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        NavigationDrawerFragment ndf = new NavigationDrawerFragment();
        ndf.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_drawer, ndf).commit();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

```
//...
<!-- ViewPager -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
     />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in `onCreate()` at the end:

```
//...
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_drawer, new NavigationDrawerFragment()).commit();
```

If you get an exception with the code above, it's in the same `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure to understand. Can you provide me some code please (it'll be really useful, i'm stuck with this problem since yesterday!). I have replaced `<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"... />` in `activity_main.xml` by `<FrameLayout ... />`. I don't understand the next part "add the NavigationDrawerFragment manually in onCreate() after the lines above" :(

Comment: That is what I need to add? In `MainActivity.java` onCreate() method (after setContentView line): `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.navigation_drawer, new NavigationDrawerFragment()).commit();`. Gives me a `.NullPointerException` (RuntimeException: Unable to start activity).

Comment: I have this error with your code: http://pastebin.com/S1Awky7g . Same error if I move getSupport... line in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` (at the top of the method). The `NullPointerException` is on this line: `mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));` . So I tried to move the `getSupportFragmentManager()...` line before. Same... :/

Comment: @Guicara I didn't saw that you tried to work with the fragment in the `onCreate()` method. I've edited my answer again. On a side note, your fragment is very complicated and also in a very tight coupling with its activity which makes working with it hard. For example, there shouldn't be any reason to pass the `R.id.navigation_drawer` back to the fragment when you can very easily use `getView()` instead in the fragment.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. But, always the NullPointer exception (on `ndf.setUp()` line). I don't understand why... PS: it is the NavigationDrawer implementation of Android Studio IDE.

Comment: @Guicara It's because what I said above. You've made your fragment to tied to the `Activity`.  If `setUp()` is called in `onCreate()` `getActivity()` will be null as the transaction is scheduled to happen in the future. You could not call `setUp()` in `onCreate()` of the Activity and call it inside the fragment(in `onActivityCreated()` for example). You need to refactor the method, you don't need to pass those parameters, as I already said, in the fragment you have `getActivity()` and through that reference you could get references to what you need(like the drawer).

Comment: So the Navigation Drawer implementation of Android Studio is wrong? "You need to refactor it": yes, that is the challenge! All I want is to have a Navigation Drawer + ViewPager (based on this code: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).  But it seems to be very complicated.

Comment: @Guicara I'm not sure about what implementation from Android Studio are you talking. Drawer + ViewPager it's easy to implement, you've complicated things a lot by introducing that fragment and making it do stuff that it shouldn't do(manipulating directly the drawer for example). This is what I was talking when I recommended a refactor. I'm not sure why you even used a fragment and not just an ordinary `ListView` with the activity doing all the stuff you currently do in the fragment. This is what you should do.

Comment: Android Studio have generated this code for me (when you add a new activity, you can select the menu: none, drawer, tabs...).

Comment: @Guicara I've seen it now. It's not that is incorrect but I don't think it's the proper way to do things. Anyway for you problem you could use another approach(keeping the initial generated code): use nested fragments. The `ViewPager` will be removed from the layout and put in the layout of another `Fragment`(so you can easily replace it with the other drawer fragments). In that `ViewPager` use your `ArticleFragments`(remember to pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to its adapter). If you want I'll post a small sample, tomorrow because it's late now.

Comment: That would be awesome! In the meantime, I will look into the functioning of "Nested fragments".

Comment: @Guicara Take a look at https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/f04c39dc75b4a9a31aff8be3beb872a698788cbe/src/com/luksprog/playground/app/DrawerPagerImpl.java The code is basically the initial code of the drawer template in Android studio, I've added some classes and changed the import to use the support library classes). It's something very basic but see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's awesome!!. But how can I attach a layout to ArticleFragment? I have tried to add `ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);` on the `onCreateView()` of ArticleFragment, but I have `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`. I think it's because we now use nested fragments?

Comment: Everything works well now. I have edited your code to support XML layout (on PagerHolderFragment and ArticleFragment). Your help was very useful.

Comment: @Luksprog: Any idea, how on back button press we can close the nav drawer(if it is in the open state) from the main activity?

Comment: @Basher51 The DrawerLayout has a method isDrawerOpen() to check if it's open. Using that you could then override the activity's onBackPressed() and close the drawer with closeDrawer().